# How to get SAML from Ping Federate IDP?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml, pingfederate

I had set up IDP using Ping Federate. On successful user authentication, PF IDP generates SAML. It is stored in server.log

How do I get the SAML through http Request? I am trying to validate SAML using openSAML rather than using PF on the SP side.

Please help.

Thanks,
Aswini J

Comment: It doesn't store the response in the server.log - it records the transaction there. Have you shared metadata between the systems? Have you gone through the OpenSAML documentation? Do you know how to create a connection in OpenSAML? Have you created a new connection in PingFederate to point to the OpenSAML implementation? Your question gives us no information about what you've done, whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to see the SAML flow through either SAML tracer or fiddler, it will show you the both SAML request and response in a clear way with the http requests.

In fiddler tracer you have a option called HTTPS decrypt by checking this you can see all the traffic happening between the client and server in browser. Let me know if you need any clarification in this.
Thanks,
Gowthaman. P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used tamper data in firefox to see the traffic between client and browser. There is an intermediary link (Referer) which posts the SAML to SP ACS. When I tried to get SAML from that referer, it says link expired.

Comment: What do you mean "tried to get SAML from that referer"? What are you trying to do (big picture) and why? Unfortunately, your original question is not clear enough to really understand. Can you please edit it and explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want see the actions of SAML happening in browser best way is go with SAML Tracer in firefox and Fiddler in IE, please elaborate your question to make us understand easily..